# PowerShell scripting with New-Timespan

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I want to do a `New-Timespan` thing to find out how long a process is running.

So, first thing I did is declared a variable and `Get-Process` it.

ex: `$np = Get-Process notepad`

Now I want to create a variable named Time create a timespan object to calculate when notepad was started. Can I use any parameter to indicate when the `New-Timespan` object is to begin and then using dot notation append the start time of Notepad as an argument? If possible I want to create a third variable called seconds and set its value equal to the timespan object reported in seconds.

Comment: Underlying problem (how long has process been running) answered [by the Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/27/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-find-how-long-a-process-runs/) back in 2013.

Comment: for example, i started the notepad and running it for long time. so, i wanna check the time how long it is running

Comment: As I said, The Scripting Guy answered that question back in 2013 - see the link in my comment.

Comment: thanks, but that is only one part. I need few more things

Comment: thanks I did it. just tell me how to get the value of a variable in echo command

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script property to standard classes.
Have a look to [about_Types.ps1xml](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh847881.aspx). By default, PowerShell loads several type extensions from the Types.ps1xml file in PowerShell's installation directory. You can write your one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Types>
    <Type>
       <Name>System.Diagnostics.Process</Name>
          <Members>
              <ScriptProperty>
                  <Name>RunningTime</Name>
                  <GetScriptBlock>
                     New-TimeSpan -Start $this.StartTime
                  </GetScriptBlock>
              </ScriptProperty>
          </Members>
    </Type>
</Types>
```

Then copy it to `$PSHOME` as `Types.Custom.ps1xml` for example with the command :

```
update-typedata -prependpath $pshome\Types.Custom.ps1xml
```

Then you've got your new property, you just have to register this command in your profile to have it in all your sessions.
[image: RunningTime Ex]